# Android columns in xml

Tags: android

I want to create a table with 5 columns and each column should have 5 rows how can i do this ? it should not be made pragmatically i have tried this but this gives errors

```
    <TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="38dp" >

    <TableColumn
        android:id="@+id/table1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableColumn>

    <TableColumns
        android:id="@+id/table2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableColumns>

    <TableColumns
        android:id="@+id/table3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableColumns>

    <TableColumns
        android:id="@+id/table4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableColumns>
    <TableColumns
        android:id="@+id/table5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </TableColumns>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: Had you try LinearLayout?

Comment: No i have not tried it

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
<TableLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="430dp"
android:shrinkColumns="1" >

                    <!-- Row 1 with single column -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">
                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_span="2"
                            android:padding="10dip"
                            android:gravity="center" />
                   </TableRow>

                    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView1"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    </TableRow>

                    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView3"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                         <TextView

                             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                             android:gravity="left"
                             android:lines="1"
                             android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                             android:paddingRight="10dp"
                             android:paddingTop="10dp"
                             android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    </TableRow>



                    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView4"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    </TableRow>         
                    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView5"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    </TableRow>



                    <!-- Row 3 with 2 columns -->
                    <TableRow
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:gravity="center_horizontal">

                        <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/textView6"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                        <TextView

                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:gravity="left"
                            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
                            android:paddingRight="10dp"
                            android:paddingTop="10dp"
                            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

                    </TableRow>
```

This layout is just to give you the idea of how to achieve your requirement. Hope it helps. :)